# Objective-C Auto scroll images in a UI scroll view repeatedly, like a horizontal slide show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, autoscroll

I have a list of *images getting from database in to an iMagesArray.*

My requirement is to **display images as a slide show in a fixed size window horizontally**.

**Same  like** in **http://www.nda4u.com/** **Thank you to these 2013 NDA Convention Sponsors:** line

Comment: Do you want the images to be auto-scrolling or scroll on user interaction?

Comment: auto Scrolling images

Comment: Should the rotation loop once it reaches the end? Do you have the images as urls or you have the actual image data?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
//...
int i;
}
-(void) viewDidLoad{
//... whatever wour code in the view is...
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(animation:) userInfo:Nil repeats:Yes];
}

-(void)animation{
    i++;
    //i'd name the images just with numbers
    int newView = mod(i,numberOfImagesInSlideShow);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mod(i,numberOfTotalImages);]
    UIImageView newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
    self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(-self.bounds.size.width/numberOfImagesInSlideShow,self.bounds.size.height/2);

    [self addSubView:newImageView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        for(int n=0;n<numberOfImagesInSlideShow;n++){
            if([self viewWithTag:(mod(i+n,numberOfImagesInSlideShow))])
                [self viewWithTag:(mod(i+n,numberOfImagesInSlideShow))].center = CGPointMake(n*self.bounds.size.width/numberOfImagesInSlideShow,self.bounds.size.height/2);
        }
     }                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if([self viewWithTag:(mod(mod(i+numberOfImagesInSlideShow-1,numberOfImagesInSlideShow)))])
                [[self viewWithTag:(mod(i+numberOfImagesInSlideShow-1,numberOfImagesInSlideShow))] removeFromSuperView];
     }];
```